# How to create mp4 file from h264 encoded frames on android?

Tags: android, h.264, mp4

I have some h264 frames already encoded with android encoder. Now i want to create and write them one by one to the mp4 file. Please advise how to do this on android in Java. I don't want to use OpenCV or native code.

mp4-parser can't do this as i understand

navite MPEG4Writer is too complicated to use

Wondering why such a common and very useful thing as mp4 writer NOT FROM CAMERA is not implemented in android

Answer (score 1):

You may use my [mp4parser](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) project. You can mux H264 and AAC in pure Java with it:

```
    H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new FileInputStream("raw.h264").getChannel());
    Movie m = new Movie();
    m.addTrack(h264Track);

    IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("h264_output.mp4"));
    out.getBox(fos.getChannel());
    fos.close();
```

Comment: this will produce an mp4 file that would likely play too fast. refer to this SO item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738890/what-governs-playback-speed-when-encoding-with-androids-mediacodec-mp4parser